# When does the integral vanish?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $\mu$ be a positive Borel measure on $(0,1)$ and $g \in L^2(\mu)$ be such that $\|g\|_2 = 1.$ Then does there exist $f \in C_0 ((0,1))$ such that $\int_{(0,1)} |g|^2 (f - 1)\ d\mu = 0\ $?

If we can show that the above integral is zero iff $f - 1 = 0$ almost everywhere then by continuity of $f$ we have $f \equiv 1$ on $(0,1).$ But then $f \notin C_0((0,1))$ for otherwise it approaches to $0$ near the endpoints which is not the case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose $C_0(0,1)$ stands for continuous functions on $(0,1)$ which tend to $0$ as $x \to  0$ or $x \to 1$.
Take $f(x)=cx(1-x)$ You can quickly solve the given equation for $c$. Note that $\int_0^{1} x(1-x)|g(x)|^{2}dx \neq 0$.

[ We need $c \int_0^{1} x(1-x)|g(x)|^{2}d\mu =\int |g|^{2}d\mu$ which is satisfied when $c=\frac {\int |g|^{2}d\mu} {\int_0^{1} x(1-x)|g(x)|^{2}d\mu}$]

Comment: I need $\int_{0}^{1} (f - 1) |g|^2 = 0$; not $\int_{0}^{1} f\ |g|^2 = 0.$ If you take $f : x \mapsto x(1-x)$ then what about the integral $\int_{0}^{1} (x(1 - x) - 1) |g(x)|^2\ dx\ $? Can it still be concluded to be non-zero for all $g \in L^2*\mu)$ with $\|g\|_2 = 1\ $?

Comment: I said nothing about $\int f|g|^{2}=0$.  I have added some details. @AnilBagchi

Comment: @AnilBagchi Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I misinterpreted your solution. Sorry for that.